# How to enable/display a download button in google docs gview embedded in a webview iframe

Tags: cordova, iframe, google-docs, google-document-viewer

I have a cordova/ionic app that is successfully embedding office files (IE: pdf, doc, xls) using gview in an iframe.  However, the user can only just view the doc and there appears now way for the user to download the file.

`https://docs.google.com/gview?url=" +$scope.docPath+ "&embedded=true"`

The full iframe: `<iframe id="viewerFrame" style="width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" ng-src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://exmple.com/files/5372967.pdf?t=1694794056384&amp;embedded=true"></iframe>`

The embedded link includes the options passed to google docs; so to enable a download button of some sort it must be included in the embedded link.

**Context**:  As of Android 12+, due to the new scoped storage on Android apps can no longer download files directly to the phones common `Downloads` folder forcing you to use a different methodology.  Using a standard anchor tag with `download` doesn't work in apps anyway.  So I was trying to see if a native download button from within in the embedded document viewer would treat the download as a browser would versus as how an app would be doing it.

The embedded view has a "pop-out" button.  But when embedded in an iFrame, the pop-out button causes the app to crash (i have no idea why)...so I am hiding the pop-out button.

There seems to be no official documentation for gview too.  I did find this very limited SE on gview options, but nothing there indicates enabling a download button.  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130654/all-google-docs-url-parameters-functions-commands

Is there any gview option that would display a functioning download button?

Comment: Can you share with us what you have done so far (with [minimal reproducible example or share your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) so that we can better help you.

Comment: I added the iFrame...but the reality is its a google doc option that needs to be passed in the embedded link

Comment: @KJ - you mentioned that in another comment, that my links are `http` - they are not, they are listed as `https` in the sample code.  Yes, I changed the url being passed to gview so as to not list my real domain, which is common practice on SO.  And yes, currently I have the iFrame sandboxed, but if I could get a download button in the embedded doc viewer then I would need to alter that so the button could work.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a link yourself

```
 <div class="wrapper">
      <a href="https://exmple.com/files/5372967.pdf?t=1694794056384" download>Download</span>
      <iframe ...></iframe>
 </div>

 .wrapper{
      display: flex;
      height: 100%;
      flex-direction: column      
 }
 .wrapper > *{
      display: inline-block;
 }
 .wrapper > iframe{
      flex-grow: 1;
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean? Can't you create the iframe inside a div ?

Comment: hi guys, that would work for a standard browser page but not for a mobile app using cordova or other framework on Android.  On Android 12+, they have prevented apps downloading directly to the phones common `Downloads` folder forcing you to use a different methodology.  Using a standard anchor tag with `download` doesn't work in apps anyway.  So I was trying to see if if a native download button in the embedded document viewer would treat the download as a browser would versus as how an app would be doing it.  Going to update OP to clarify things.